# Duplicate jar entry when using firebase-analytics:16.0.5

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

**officially fixed in ads 17.1.1 (developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)**

---

After updating the version of firebase-analytics from 16.0.4 to 16.0.5
The project failed to build release aab/apk, with error message `Duplicate jar entry [com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzdz.class]`

Android Studio 3.2.1

app's build.gradle

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
```

Project build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [MASKED\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\0.jar] (Can't read [MASKED\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\release\21(;;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't read [com] (Can't read [google] (Can't read [android] (Can't read [gms] (Can't read [internal] (Can't read [measurement] (Can't read [zzdz.class] (Duplicate jar entry [com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzdz.class])))))))))    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:202)     at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:89)  at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:515)     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:210)     at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:262)    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:65)     at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:176)     at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)   at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)  ... 1 more
```

Any workaround before they release a fix?

Comment: Having the same problem with Android Studio 3.4 Canary 3 and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha03'`, `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`, `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'` and `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'`. With core 16.0.4 everything is fine.

Comment: officially fixed in ads 17.1.1
(https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used `gradlew :app:dependencies` and found some dependencies are not using the most updated version.

manually added the following dependency for overriding the version loaded can solve the problem.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0'
```

Comment: I just needed this line `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.0.3'`

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced this issue, try to update google play services version to latest one and also update all firebase libraries you are using. 
As of Android Studio 3.2.1 following is latest:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: all dependencies are in the newest version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'

Comment: Then firebase libraries need be to latest too, All of them

Answer (score 0):

This is simple solution,

Google has fixed the issue, all you need to do is update ads gradle version to 17.1.1, this will solve the problem of firebase-core:16.0.5, add the below lines will solve the problem

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
```